# 'Add New' button not present

Tags: themes

I am trying to install a Wordpress theme to my site, however no 'Add New' button is showing, as in this screenshot:
[image]

The same section in my Admin Panel looks like this:

[image]

I've done some searching, and apparently the 'Add New' button is removed on Wordpress.com sites, but this doesn't apply to my since I'm hosting the Wordpress installation on my own host.
It can't be disabling it because of space limitations, since I have unlimited space:
[image]

I know I can install it manually, but I do not want to mess up the Wordpress installation so naturally I do not want to try this (just in case it messes the site up later).

Why is this happening, and how can I fix this?

***Edit:***
A different site I host with the same company, even on the *same* physical server computer, with the same Wordpress version, has the button:
[image]

Comment: Does the user you are logged-in with have sufficient rights to add new themes?

Comment: @ialocin Yes, this is a new Wordpress installation and I'm logged in with the only admin account.

Comment: Did you check the file/folder permissions?

Comment: have you tried switching to the deafult theme with all plugins deactivated?

Comment: Is that a WordPress multisite installation ?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I also don't have an "add new" button despite being the only user on a totally new account

Comment: @user65565 It's a bug with the WP admin panel, apparently. The only thing that worked was to reinstall it. I also got a moderator to move your question to a comment for you :).